# how to update or change images of imageview dynamically in android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to update my imageview with diffrent images within a specific time using timer or thread ?

Answer (score 20):

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
```

use the above code to set an image to the image view and use a thread that can change contents in the UI bascially some thing like this

```
public void onClick(View v) {
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
     ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
   }
  }).start();
}
```

Comment: i want to change 8 images in imageview within 20 secs using timer or thread.i done iot but its not updating the UI.so only first image is showing. i want without any button click or any events

Comment: this code will update only once. i want to update it 8 times with diffrent images.

Comment: timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            // Task here ...
        }
    }, delay, period);   use this code to set a repeating task ....

Answer (score 0):

hi check this post here is the exampel for imageview to display images in image view

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-gallery-imageview-example

here is main portion for set the image in imageview

```
imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
```

Comment: yes this is for images for update. for e.g. whatever image you want to display you can access R.drawable.<img_name> that will be pass here so in thread or any timer code this line of code is use it

Comment: i want to change 8 images in imageview within 20 secs using timer or thread.i done iot but its not updating the UI.so only first image is showing

Comment: try this code after set the the resource invalidateDrawable(Drawable  dr)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply set the image URI:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Uri uri;
            if (data != null) {
                uri = data.getData();
                iv030.setImageURI(uri);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),uri.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.test_image)

button.setOnClickListener{
    Log.i("Info", "Button Pressed")
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_image2)
}
```

Comment: Question is about updating ImageView with Timer or thread. Your answer is irrelevant.

Comment: Question is about frequently changing images

Comment: this image update is for use once only.. but you can use "Boolean" for switching Images

Answer (score 0):

Try with `setImageResource()` method to change the image dynamically. Add the drawable image reference as the parameter to change the image.

The sample code is given below,

```
package com.vsoft.imagechanger;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 ImageView ChangeImage;
 Button ChangeButton;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 
    ChangeButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    ChangeImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 
    ChangeButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
 
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
          //ChangeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.xxx);
          ChangeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.imageView2)
       }
    });
 }
}
```